# Numerical integration involving divergence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I was just trying to perform the following numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[1/(x - 5)^2, {x, 0, 10}]
```

The  problem I am facing is the divergence at `x = 5`. If anyone has any idea on how I can deal with divergences and singularities in numerical integration, I would be very thankful for their advice.

Comment: What result are you hoping for, considering that the integral doesn't in a strict sense actually converge over that range?

Comment: `Integrate[1/(x - 5)^2, {x, 0, 10}]` will tell you that the integral does not converge. Therefore, there is no use trying `NIntegrate`.

Comment: With **Regularization**: `Limit[Integrate[1/(x - (5 + I*e))^2, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Assumptions -> e > 0], e -> 0]`.See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86468/regularization-and-int-0-infty-sin-x-mathrmdx

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: The above results in `-2/5`, i.e. the increment of its antiderivative `-1/(x-5)` from `0` to `10`. A good regularization should to satisfy certain conditions.

Comment: The `NIntegrate` command has an option `Method->PrincipalValue` to numerically calculate some principal values of integrals. However, in the case under consideration any principal value does not exist.